# symfony 2.8 AppKernel slowness

Tags: symfony, amazon-ec2, datadog, php-5.6, symfony-2.8

We need your help/opinion on some issues we're having with slowness in our production app. Some context: we have two AWS EC2 servers (t3a.2xlarge) running a symfony 2.8 app (php 5.6) through php-fpm/nginx, which connects mostly to mariadb, but also sometimes to mongodb.

When we have less than ~700-800 users, the performance is ok. With more than that, we start to have some serious performance problems, and the CPU of the machines reaches 80-100%.

In one of those moments, for a simple API call, our datadog shows the following trace:

[image: symfony 2.8 trace]

The AppKernel is taking 7 seconds until the first mysql query is done. That controller action code is quite simple, the problem is not in that code. In a normal situation, this call takes 200ms total. We have this same problem in other controllers actions. We already fine tuned a lot of the php-fpm and opcache parameters to:

```
pm.max_children: 216
pm.start_servers: 54
pm.max_spare_servers: 162
pm.min_spare_servers: 54
pm.process_idle_timeout: 10s
pm.max_requests: 500
realpath_cache_size: 4096k
realpath_cache_ttl: 300
```

We're basically struggling a bit to find the real cause of this slowness. Is it just a matter of cpu, because the php5.6/symfony 2.8 is a slow and old stack? Or is there some fine-tuning we can make so that the AppKernel becomes faster?

Although we are migrating all this stack to a more recent one, we still have plenty of symfony 2.8 code running with php 5.6, so this is still pretty important to us.

I would really appreciate your help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Additional DB information request from your MariaDB, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.